# How do I tell which commands will use brace expansion and which won't?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, brace-expansion

For instance, this works:

`$ curl -s -X GET  "http://api-int.abc.com/api/{,,,}ukulele/v1/health"`

This runs 4 curl commands, which is what I want.

Meanwhile `ping` won't use brace expansion:

```
$ ping {google,yahoo,microsoft}.com
usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-b boundif] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize]
```

But touch will:

`$ touch .temp/{a,b,c}.txt`

Creates three files.

How would I know from the man page for these commands which ones can use brace expansion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that some commands allow multiple arguments and some do not. While `touch` allows multiple arguments, `ping` does not. In the case of `ping`, the braces are expanding to multiple  and calling ping with multiple arguments, which `ping` will not do. A for loop is a better solution in this case. Also, the braces in `curl` are a special case (see below).

The answer to "which commands can use brace expansion" is all and none. The brace expansion is done by the shell, before passing the expanded output to the command. In other words, the command being launched is completely irrelevant. The expansion of `foo{bar,baz}` to `foobar foobaz` is done by the shell before launching the command and passing the expanded string as parameters to it.

However, brace expansion does not occur inside quotes. In other words, both `"{,,,}"` and `"{a,b,c}"` remain as strings and are not expanded:

```
$ echo "{,,,}"
{,,,}
$ echo "{a,b,c}"
{a,b,c}
```

To get expansion to work, you should remove the quotes:

```
$ echo {,,,}  ## this expands to a blank string, so this is what is printed

$ echo {a,b,c}
a b c
```

This is documented in the relevant section of `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> **Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions**, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result.  It is strictly  textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces.
>
> **A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain  unquoted  opening  and closing  braces**,  and  at  least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression.

Now, the reason you are confused is that `curl` actually has its own parser and that also handles brace expansion. This is done independently of the shell and is explained in `man curl`:

> You can specify multiple URLs or parts of URLs  by  writing  part 
>   sets    within braces as in:
>
> ```
>  http://site.{one,two,three}.com
> ```

So, any command can work with brace expansion since it isn't actually the command working with it, but the shell that expands the expression in the braces before calling the command. Curl is confusing because it has its own, similar feature.